# Does there always exist such orthonormal basis in $R^3$ that all the three vectors lie in one coordinate octant?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

There are three such vectors in the Euclidean space $E^3$ that all their pairwise inner
products are non-negative. Does there always exist such orthonormal basis in $R^3$
that all these three vectors lie in one coordinate octant?

From the first part, I understand that these three vectors will be having the same signs respectively such that their pairwise inner dot product is non-negative. But the second of the question is quite confusing. I do not understand what is the question trying to ask. Is it asking to find an orthonormal basis that is orthogonal to all the three vectors such that they all lie in one octant?  But since the vectors are arbitrary it is not easy to find the orthonormal vector. How should I proceed?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the standard basis count? Is it the closed octant or the open octant (if the latter, then the answer will be no)?

Comment: @GregMartin I was trying to do with a standard basis only but I am not quite sure. Nothing related to the standard basis or about the octant has been mentioned in the question.

Comment: To be honest the two sentences don't seem to have much to do with each other. If the three vectors from the first sentence are supposed to be orthonormal, that already tells us that the pairwise inner products are $0$—why bother saying they're nonnegative?

Comment: @GregMartin exactly !! It's bit confusing